# How can I prevent notifyItemChanged() from killing the ripple effect when selecting an item in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, ripple

I have a `RecyclerView` and I would like to allow users to select views using a long press. This works fine except that the ripple effect is terminated as soon as I call either `notifyItemChanged()` or `notifyDataSetChanged` in order to indicate the selection. How can I prevent this from happening?

Note, this question has been asked before ([Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543044/retain-ripple-effect-during-notifydatachanged-in-recyclerview), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191427/recyclerview-item-not-showing-ripples-touch-feedback-when-the-item-has-a-checkbo)). The answer to those questions has been to use `notifyItemChanged` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`. I have tried both of these and it does not change the behavior for me.

Comment: I am using drawable as background so you dont need to notify any change just checkout my question : [RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862718/binary-xml-file-line-error-inflating-class-unknown) Find state.xml and try to do something like that

Comment: That would be a good option if just a background color was acceptable but I really want to make more active changes to the view.

Comment: Can you specify more with that "active changes"

Comment: I have a custom view inside that handles changing a border size and displays a different image.

Comment: Override onSelected in custom View. If selected, change bordersize etc and invalidate.

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of notifyItemChanged() method. One takes only position and the other one takes position and a payload.

And in my case the first one broke the ripple effect, while the second one worked. At least when I passed the object that just has been changed as the payload.

Answer (score 0):

a) add DiffUtilCallback to your adapter

b) make sure what your `areItemsTheSame` method compare items by id and not by content.
Because if it compare by content, it thinks what you remove previous cell and insert new, and kill ripple effect.